# Retrofit get String response

Tags: android, retrofit, android-networking

Is it possible to recieve only String response using Retrofit library? I have a situation where I need to add Query on my link so that link is looking like :
localhost//Register?handle=SomeID

SomeID is integer and when I do that I will receive response from server in string format that consist of 20 chars. How can I get that response? Can Retrofit even handle response that is not in Json format?

Also how should I create this :

@GET("/api/UserMainInformations")
    Call getUserMainInfo();

That's example from some other call but now I won't have any model to send it cuz I only add it on Query. What should i put in Call<> ;

Comment: do not spam with irrelevant tags

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get the response from api and convert it to string like this:

```
 public interface RetrofitService{
        @GET("/users")
        Call<ResponseBody> listRepos();//function to call api
    }

    RetrofitService service = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> result = service.listRepos(username);
    result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
            System.out.println(response.body().string());//convert reponse to string
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: `ResponseBody` is OkHttp3 class.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

Api interface:

```
public interface APIService {
@GET("api/get_info")
    Call<ResponseBody> getInfo();//import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
}
```

Api call:

```
// Retrofit service creation code skipped here
String json = retrofitService().getInfo().execute().body().string();
```

It worked for me. I use retrofit:2.1.0.