# SwitchCompat in ListView to make network call

Tags: android, listview, retrofit, retrofit2, switchcompat

I have SwitchCompat inside a listView item , I want this SwitchCompat State to be sent to my remote database every time i change it ON/OFF for the specific item, I tried to put this network call in the adapter but i got the Exception: NetworkOnMainThreadException

any help?

I am using Retrofit for the network call

My Adapter

> Adapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ExpensesHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ExpensesHolder();
        ...
        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ExpensesHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    holder.switchExpenses.setTag(position);
    ...
    if (flag.equals("unselected")) {
        holder.switchExpenses.setChecked(false);

    } else {
        holder.switchExpenses.setChecked(true);

    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(expName)) {
        // want to make network call here
        }




    return row;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're calling `call.execute()`, to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException use `call.enqueue(listener)`

Comment: how to perform call.enqueue(listener) if the result will be String not json?

Comment: You can check the answer in the link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37589828/5913289]